# C # Get all content of all occurrences of a word in long string

Tags: c#, json, string

I have this string, actually in JSON format.

```
{
  "key1": val1
  "key2": val2
  .
  .
  .
  "keyN": {
    "keyN1": valN1
    "keyN2": valN2
    "keyN3": {
      "keyN3-1": valN3-1
      "keyN3-2": valN3-2
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
  "keyNN": {
    "keyNN1": valNN1
    "keyNN2": valNN2
    "keyNN3": [
        {
          "keyNN3-1": valNN3-1,
          "keyNN3-2": valNN3-2,
          "keyNN3-3": {
            "keyNN3-3-1": valueNN3-3-1,
            "keyNN3-3-2": valueNN3-3-2,
            "keyM": {
              "KeyM1": ValueM1,
              "KeyM2": ValueM2,
              .
              .
              "KeyMN": ValueMN
            }
          }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        {
          "keyNN3-1": valNN3-1,
          "keyNN3-2": valNN3-2,
          "keyNN3-3": {
            "keyNN3-3-1": valueNN3-3-1,
            "keyNN3-3-2": valueNN3-3-2,
            "keyM": {
              "KeyM1": ValueM1,
              "KeyM2": ValueM2,
              .
              .
              "KeyMN": ValueMN
            }
          }
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

I wanna get all content of key "keyM" all times that key appear, I mean, I wanna return this

```
[
  {
    "KeyM1": ValueM1,
    "KeyM2": ValueM2,
    .
    .
    "KeyMN": ValueMN
  },
  .
  .
  {
    "KeyM1": ValueM1,
    "KeyM2": ValueM2,
    .
    .
    "KeyMN": ValueMN
  }
]
```

I receive strings in different formats, first struct isn't the only struc, but always has "keyM". In this moment I'm doing whit a while but isn't efficient, I wanna know if exist a better way.

Comment: Can you clarify your expectations a little? When you say you want to "get all content", do you mean you want the entire JSON object that has a KeyM* property in it? Or just the *lines* that have those properties? Or just the Values of those properties?

Comment: Please provide your attempt in code. Thanks.

Comment: Also: can you share the code you're using to do this with a `while` loop, and elaborate on why it "isn't efficient"? Do you mean it uses lots of lines of code, or that it takes too long? If it takes too long, how big is the JSON payload you're getting?

Comment: It would also be better if you changed your example to be more concrete, for instance, are we to understand the usage of "keyM" that you want to look for keys using a suffix? Considering you've gathered keyM1, keyM2, keyM3, etc. Or is there an arbitrary rule you're checking against that just has to say "this key is an interesting one"?

Comment: Sorry for bad question, i try to clarify, with "get all content" i mean, properties and vaues that "keyM" has. In return, I wanted to show keys and values of keyM objects. With  "isn't efficient" i mean is slow, it takes too long. String can be 600,000 or more characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(initialJson);

IEnumerable<JToken> keyMs = o.SelectTokens("$..keyM");
```

Good tool for testing JsonPaths http://jsonpath.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed, I just combined it with answer of @striplingwarrior and it works excellently

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your JSON structure right, something like this should work (using JSON.NET):

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<JObject>(jsonText);
var keyMItems = jObject.SelectTokens("keyM");
```

Then what you do with those items will depend on your use case. To output something like you've listed, you could package it into a new JArray.

```
Console.WriteLine(new JArray(keyMItems).ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, your help was very useful